# how to import a DLL function written in C using GO?

Tags: c, dll, import, go

I'm looking for an example code how import a function from a dll written in C. equivalent to `DllImport` of  `C#.NET`. It's possible? 
I'm using windows.
any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsDLLs is a good resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/). [Here](http://blog.golang.org/2011/03/c-go-cgo.html)'s an introduction.

Comment: In advance, thanks for you reply. I getting the following error:`build package main:   [C:/Go/bin/8g -o teste_go_.8 main.go] main.go:5: can't find import: C Error, exit status 1exit status 1`

how I fix it?

Comment: @TheMask: That may be the subject for a different question. I don't know about using Go on Windows, but my first guess would be to check your environment variables.

Comment: @The Mask: Can you post your error and the way you fixed it as a different question (and answer)? It would probably be helpful to future seekers.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few ways to do it.

The cgo way allows you to call the function this way:

```
import ("C")
...
C.SomeDllFunc(...)
```

It will call libraries basically by "linking" against the library. You can put C code into Go and import the regular C way.

There are more methods such as syscall

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

// ..

kernel32, _        = syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
getModuleHandle, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GetModuleHandleW")
```

...

```
func GetModuleHandle() (handle uintptr) {
    var nargs uintptr = 0
    if ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getModuleHandle), nargs, 0, 0, 0); callErr != 0 {
    abort("Call GetModuleHandle", callErr)
    } else {
        handle = ret
    }
    return
}
```

There is this useful github page which describes the process of using a DLL:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

There are three basic ways to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Use the same method that the Windows port of Go does. See the source code for the Windows implementation of the Go [syscall](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package. Also, take a look at the source code for the experimental Go [exp/wingui](http://golang.org/pkg/exp/wingui/) package