# Get string data from a pointer to C-Char array

Tags: go

I got pointer to C-char array I got from C++ dll.How can i get string data?

I am using this code to get the pointer to a memory address:

Go:

```
dll, err := windows.LoadDLL("someDll.dll")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
proc := dll.MustFindProc("Function")
response, _, _ := proc.Call()
```

C++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* Function() {
    char text[] = "something";
    return text;
}
```

I've tried this:

```
fmt.Println(*(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&response)))
```

And this:

```
var data []byte
sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&data))
sh.Data = response
sh.Len = 9
sh.Cap = 9
fmt.Println(data, string(data))
```

but nothing works for me.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to do in these examples. Are you looking for `C.GoString`?

Comment: I am trying to read string data from memory. You've said that I can use `C.GoString`. How can I use it?

Comment: The signature of C.GoString is fairly clear, `func C.GoString(*C.char) string`.  Pass it a pointer to the first char, as is normal usage in C.  It will scan up to the first null byte and convert that, less the null byte, into a Go string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example C++ code is ... not good, as it returns a pointer to a variable whose storage has been released.  Use `static char text[]` or similar to fix it.  Real C or C++ code will return either a pointer to memory that should be released with `free`, or not, and you will need to handle these cases too.

Still, you can get some or most of the way to what you want with `cgo`, which is built in to Go these days.  Note that when using cgo, you need a separate `import "C"` statement, generally prefixed with a comment.  (You cannot put this import into the regular import section.)

Let's cover all this in several parts.

#### No DLL, C code that returns pointer to `static` storage-duration `char`s

If we ignore all the DLL aspects, and assume that you can link directly against a particular C function that returns `char *`, the example Go code to work with it would be:

```golang
package main

/*
extern char *Function();
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func WrapFunction() string {
    return C.GoString(C.Function())
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(WrapFunction())
}
```

I put a sample `Function()` in a file by itself named `cgo.go` in a directory with just the one `.c` file, `function.c`, as well.  Here's the very simple C code for this particular `Function()`:

```c
char *Function() {
    return "hello";
}
```

(A C string literal has type `char [N]` with the integer constant `N` determined at compile time, and static duration, and C has that funny rule of "decaying" an array to a pointer to its first element, so we meet our goal of returning `char *` pointing to static-duration memory.)

```
$ go build
$ ./cgo
hello
$
```

#### C code that returns pointer to dynamically-allocated memory

Let's say instead that the C (or wrapped C++) function uses `malloc` (or `new`) to allocate the string, so that we must free it.  Here's the updated `function.c` that does so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *Function() {
    char *text = malloc(25); /* big enough for hello and a number */
    if (text != NULL) {
        srand(time(NULL));   /* should do this just once, really */
        sprintf(text, "hello %d", rand() % 100);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Then we would rewrite `cgo.go` as:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
extern char *Function();
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func WrapFunction() string {
    s := C.Function()
    // Optional -- note that C.free(nil) is a no-op,
    // and (by experimentation) C.GoString(nil) returns "".
    // So, if it's OK to use "" if `C.Function` returns NULL,
    // skip this test-and-panic.
    if s == nil {
        panic("C.Function returned NULL")
    }
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
    return C.GoString(s)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(WrapFunction())
}
```

Compiling and running this shows:

```
$ go build
$ ./cgo
hello 27
```

See also https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo and https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/.

#### DLLs

Both of the above assume that the C wrapper is in the build directory.  Running `go build` discovers this and builds `function.c` to an object file, adds all the necessary runtime interface between C and Go, and invokes the function `Function` directly, by name.

If you must determine the function name at runtime, you have a much more serious problem.  The heart of the issue is that you cannot get assistance from `cgo` to wrap the function directly, because cgo needs to see the function's name, in that comment above the `import "C"` line.

See [how to import a DLL function written in C using GO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8231618/1256452) for several approaches.  Another one not listed there is to do the DLL lookup in a C wrapper that you write yourself.  Use `cgo` to pass the name of the function to look up, and all the (fixed) arguments.  Then you're calling a known (compile-time) function with a known (compile-time) return type and value, which simplifies the problem.  The cgo runtime wrapper will insert the appropriate runtime stack-switching for your known function, so that you do not have to use the `syscall` wrappers.

Comment: Malloc doesn't guarantee that allocated space will be zeroed, so do not suggest that for regular cases, it causes undefined behavior as well.

Comment: @LaevusDexter: I'm not suggesting that *you* call malloc. I'm suggesting that if you import some existing C library, it may *already* call malloc. If it did, you need to know to call, or have it call, free afterward. The same goes when you invoke existing C++ code, however you do it. (If your case is particularly tricky, consider using SWIG, though I have not experimented with SWIG.)